# Best solution to Node.js Sessions/Cookies

Tags: node.js, session-cookies

First off, I DONT want to use a Node.js Framework. I am working on a CMS system and have most of it working. Now I am trying to decide the best approach to Sessions.

```
Option 1: Read/Write from a file
Option 2: Read/Write from variable in mem
Option 3: Read/Write from MongoDB collection
```

I am swaying towards the MongoDB option, That way if you have the CMS across multiple servers, your session would stay live as they all are using the same MongoDB.

Anyone have any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: "Best" by what criteria? Performance? Persistence? Number of concurrent sessions it's able to handle?

Comment: You might want to consider redis a session store. You might also want to read the connect session middleware. Why re-invent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 3: It's all going to the filesystem either way.  Whatever is easier to implement and you get the most use out of.